# Why does Docker layer not showing up "RUN" command

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-layer

I am currently investigating image layers correspond to a Docker image. I see that some instructions do not begin with RUN command. Please find a portion of code snippet below.

```
1
ARG RELEASE
2
ARG LAUNCHPAD_BUILD_ARCH
3
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu
4
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.version=20.04
5
ADD file:8b1<some_hash>c in /
6
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
7
ENV <some_environment>
8
ENV <sone_environment>
9
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
10
ENV TZ=Europe/London
11
apt-get clean
12
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

In the lines 11 and 12 in this code snippet contains shell commands. I was expecting to see `RUN /bin/sh` command prior to `apt-get clean` and `apt-get update ..` commands. I'd like to know why these layers do not contain `RUN /bin/sh`.

My objective is to reproduce Docker image from the image layers as I don't have the access to the original Docker image.

Comment: Please provide a public example image, or show the exact command run that others could use to reproduce the output above. See [mcve] for more details.